# How to change the Zend_Rest_Server response header 'zend' to "my_api"?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-rest

I use Zend Rest Server class to handle rest srvice:

```
 public function restAction() {
        $service = new Zend_Rest_Server();
        $service->setClass($this->_serviceClassName);
        $service->handle();
    }
```

In the Zend_Rest_Server the response header

```
<myApi generator="zend" version="1.0">
```

How to change the **generator** to different string?

Thanks Arman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found not so elegant solution but it works:

```
 $service->returnResponse(TRUE);
 $response = $service->handle();

 header('Content-Type: text/xml');

 // replace generator="zend" with my_app
 echo str_replace('generator="zend"', 'generator="my_app"', $response);
```